# Xamarin Forms dependency service não funciona com generics?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms, injeção-de-dependência

Preciso gerar um instância de uma classe genérica com Xamarim forms utilizando dependcy service (ou um framework de DI). Com o código abaixo consigo gerar uma instância sem problemas:

> **Interface**
>
> ```
> namespace PrismNinjectApp1.Application.Interfaces
> {
>     public interface IUserService { }
> }
> ```
>
> **Concrete class**
>
> ```
> [assembly: Dependency(typeof(PrismNinjectApp1.Application.DomainServices.UserService))]
> namespace PrismNinjectApp1.Application.DomainServices
> {
>     public class UserService : IUserService
>     {
>         public UserService() { }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> **View Model**
>
> ```
> namespace PrismNinjectApp1.ViewModels
> {
>     public class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
>     {
>         private readonly IUserService _userService;
>
>         public MainPageViewModel()
>         {
>             _userService = DependencyService.Get<IUserService>();
>         }
>         //Implementation of INavigationAware interface (I'm using Prism)
>     }
> }
> ```

Mas se utilizar o código abaixo o valor retornado para a variável _myInterface  sempre é nulo

> **Interface**
>
> ```
> namespace PrismNinjectApp1.test
> {
>     public interface IMyInterface<T> where T : class { }
> }
> ```
>
> **Concrete class**
>
> ```
> [assembly: Dependency(typeof(PrismNinjectApp1.test.MyInterface<>))]
> namespace PrismNinjectApp1.test
> {
>     public class MyInterface<T> : IMyInterface<T> where T : class { }
> }
> ```
>
> **View Model**
>
> ```
> namespace PrismNinjectApp1.ViewModels
> {
>     public class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
>     {
>         private readonly IMyInterface<Users> _myInterface;
>
>         public MainPageViewModel()
>         {
>             _myInterface = DependencyService.Get<IMyInterface<Users>>(); //Gets NULL value
>         }
>         //Implementation of INavigationAware interface (I'm using Prism)
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> **Users** class is a domain entity
>
> ```
> public class Users
>     {
>         [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
>         public int Id { get; set; }
>         [MaxLength(100)]
>         public string Name { get; set; }
>     }
> ```

É possível gerar essa instancia do objeto com dependency service?

Estou tentando fazer essa implementação para utilizar serviços e repositórios genéricos.

**Versão do Xamarin Forms:** 2.3.4.247